# JQ number output format

Tags: jq

For an input below:

```
abc@abc:~$ curl https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=btc-doge | jq ".result.Ask"
```

Output to jq:

`{"success":true,"message":"","result":"Bid":0.00000034,"Ask":0.00000035,"Last":0.00000035}}`

Output from jq:

```
3.5e-07
```

how in JQ switch number output format `3.5e-07` to `0.00000035` ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not ideal, but you can use `printf` to format a number in scientific notation as a decimal.

```
$ printf '%.8f' $(curl -s https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=btc-doge | jq ".result.Ask")
0.00000035
```

The `.8` in the printf command is specifying 8 places of precision. You can specify `.10` and you will get:

```
0.0000003500
```

Or specify lower precision  `.4` and lose data.

```
0.0000
```

Comment: it work  `curl -s https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=btc-doge | jq ".result.Ask" | awk {' printf "%.8f",$1 '}`

Comment: main i forgot  in BASH - linux

Comment: @deathfish if this answer led to your solution you should mark it so.